# Create Tmux pane with sudo from sudoed pane?

Tags: sudo, zsh, tmux

I'm unclear on the terminology here, so please bear with me.

I use Tmux. I `sudo foo` in my current pane. It prompts for my password; I enter it. Now, for a while, the pane doesn't have to prompt again for my password when I `sudo` things.

However, if I make a new pane in the current window (e.g. to edit a file while keeping the original pane visible), and I `sudo bar`, it will prompt for my password again.

Is there a way to pass the "sudo unlocked" state of the first pane to the second one at the moment I create it?

For what it's worth, my shell is Zsh.

To be clear: I'm expecting a Tmux answer here, perhaps a way to change my window-splitting bindings to execute some command upon creating a pane. But I'd also be interested in other ways to configure this behaviour.

Comment: Research material: `man 5 sudoers`, search for `tty_tickets`. It looks like you can configure `sudo` to keep a single ticket for *all your panes and everything else*. But you want to escalate the new pane only, right? I expect it's hard to trick `sudo` it runs under the same controlling terminal as the old pane. Let's *suppose* you can do this somehow. Then `sudo` will spawn the actual command with "counterfeit" terminal. But you need the command itself to use the new tty (especially in your example, where you want to edit a file interactively), so you should trick it "back" in a similar way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On your system, once `sudo` has authenticated you, the authentication is tied to the particular TTY that you ran `sudo` from.  Each pane in `tmux` has its own TTY.

`sudo` on your system uses the `tty_ticket` option by default, or it uses `timestamp_type=tty` (possibly not explicitly as it is the default).  These settings are documented in the `sudoers` manual:

> `tty_tickets`
>
> If set, users must authenticate on a per-tty basis.  With this flag
>                     enabled, `sudo` will use a separate record in the time stamp file for
>                     each terminal.  If disabled, a single record is used for all login
>                     sessions.
>
> This option has been superseded by the `timestamp_type` option.

> `timestamp_type`
>
> `sudoers` uses per-user time stamp files for credential caching.  The
>                     timestamp_type option can be used to specify the type of time stamp
>                     record used.  It has the following possible values:

The values are `global`, `ppid`, `tty` (default), and `kernel` (see the `sudoers` manual for a description of each of these).

You may want to modify your `sudoers` configuration (via the `visudo` command) to either include

```
Defaults !tty_tickets
```

or

```
Defaults timestamp_type=global
```

Either of these would tie the authentication to your current login session rather than to a particular TTY.